# Set session data during functional test

Tags: java, playframework

I am looking for a way to set session data during functional test. I want to test a logout action.

Ideally, I would like to do something like that

```
    @Test
    public void testLogout() {
        Scope.Session session = Scope.Session.current();
        session.put(Application.SESSION_USER_ID, "1");

        Response response = GET("/application/logout");

        assertEquals(null, session.get(Application.SESSION_USER_ID));
}
```

Unfortunaly, when I invoke this test, I got the following NullppointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ApplicationTest.testLogout(ApplicationTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner$StartPlay$1$1$1.execute(PlayJUnitRunner.java:73)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:265)
    at play.Invoker.invokeInThread(Invoker.java:67)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner$StartPlay$1$1.evaluate(PlayJUnitRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner.run(PlayJUnitRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:199)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: Which line is `ApplicationTest.testLogout(ApplicationTest.java:26)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure why the functional test fails, but I can explain how I would test it:

I made a normal unittest:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Session.current.set(new Session());
    Request.current.set(new Request());
    Response.current.set(new Response());
}
```

and then something like that

```
@Test
public void testLogout() {
    Session.current().put(SESSION_KEY_USERID, "1");
    Response.current().setCookie(COOKIE_NAME, "A value");
    assertNotNull(Session.current().get(SESSION_KEY_USERID));
    assertTrue(Response.current().cookies.containsKey(COOKIE_NAME));
    Cookie cookie = Response.current().cookies.get(COOKIE_NAME);
    assertFalse(Integer.valueOf(0).equals(cookie.maxAge));
    assertEquals("A value", cookie.value);
    service.logout();
    assertNull(Session.current().get(SESSION_KEY_USERID));
    cookie = Response.current().cookies.get(COOKIE_NAME);
    assertTrue(Integer.valueOf(0).equals(cookie.maxAge));
    assertEquals("", cookie.value);
}
```

I hope with this information you can solve your problem. Sorry that I don't give you a correct solution, but at the moment I loose to much time solving other peoples problems :-/

Comment: But you use it as a normal JUnit-Test not a Functionaltest? I can't imagine where there could be something NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Play is supposed to be a stateless application server. Thus, storing data in session might not be a good way to proceed.

Comment: Okay... but how can I test my logout functionality?

Comment: Well, since login is generally required to access private pages, you can "logout" and try to access a forbidden page. If you are rejected, your logout will work.

Comment: Hmm.. I think that many Play applications use session to store some user id/token or something similar

Comment: Yes, indeed, you have a play_cookie that contains an id.

Answer (score 0):

Found one blog post that creates the cookie by hand and stores it in the request : http://lenni.info/blog/2012/07/using-a-mocked-session-when-writing-tests-for-play-framework-1-2/